# How are links from TFS Git commit stored

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2015

How/where are links from Commits on Git repos hosted in TFS stored?

We have an instance of a commit which we can see on the repo and if we look at that commit in the Web UI it points back to a work item. HOWEVER if we open the work item and look at the links that same commit does NOT appear.

Further if we look at the Discussion Only part of the history for the work items in question we can see only 5 of 6 commits noted. And just to further complicate issues there is an additional commit (by a different user) that does not appear in the history but for which there is a link.

Does anyone know what might be happening? I can believe a user might have deleted one of the links in the work item but even then I would expect to see something in the history for this as well as the other commit.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How/where are links from Commits on Git repos hosted in TFS stored?

In the TFS database. When a Git commit contains a reference to a work item, and auto-linking work items is enabled, then when that commit is pushed to the server, the links are created. But that is a one-time operation. Once it's done, the links can be freely edited within TFS, but the changes are only visible using the TFS interface (either web UI or API). The commit can no longer be edited, as editing it would change its hash, so no synchronisation can be done.

> Further if we look at the Discussion Only part of the history for the work items in question we can see only 5 of 6 commits noted. And just to further complicate issues there is an additional commit (by a different user) that does not appear in the history but for which there is a link.

From what I've seen, only the auto-linked commits show up in Discussion Only. That other commit would only be visible when looking at the complete history. In there, you can see who added it and when. Similarly, if a link was there in the past, whether auto-linked or manually added, but has since been deleted, the complete history would show who deleted it and when.

Comment: I have gone through each and every entry in the history for the work item and there is not reference to the commit at all. No adds. No deletes. I cannot see any reference to the commit from the work item. The only reference is FROM the commit TO the work item. We found the commit by looking at the Git log.then looked up the commit using the WebUI for TFS/Git. That's when we saw the link to the work item we cannot explain. That's why I asked where it was stored and if there is a way to get any more info about this link.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how this was done.

There is a function in the TFS UI that lets you add a comment to an existing commit. Once you navigate to a commit there is a small comment balloon with a green plus sign. The hoverover text reads "Add an overall comment for this commit". If you add a reference to a work item by entering something like #123456 it will draw a connection between the commit and the work item. However it will NOT create a link in the Work item nor will it add an entry to the history for that work item.

This is a sort of one way link that is, I suspect, not what Microsoft intended as it sets up an inconsistency in the way links between work items are implemented.